# PHPMyAdmin: Create MySQL Table from SQLite data

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

I have an SQLite Table created with this parameters:

```
CREATE TABLE "shopList" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  NOT NULL  UNIQUE , "name" TEXT NOT NULL , "address" TEXT NOT NULL , "city" TEXT NOT NULL , "state" TEXT NOT NULL , "country" TEXT NOT NULL , "zipcode" TEXT NOT NULL , "phonect" TEXT NOT NULL , "phonearea" TEXT NOT NULL , "phonemain" TEXT NOT NULL , "phonefull" TEXT NOT NULL )
```

I would like to implement it to my MySQL Database with PHPMyAdmin, but when I insert the code it says:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''shopList' ('id' INTEGER PRIMARY KEY , 'name' TEXT NOT NULL , 'address' TEXT NOT' at line 1
```

I'm new the MySQL. What did I wrong?

Comment: I don't think you need the double quotes `"`. And do what it says... check the manual.

Comment: Replaced " to ' like it says, but didn't fixed my problems

Comment: omit them completely

Comment: You don't need single quotes too, table and variable names should be as they are, or in inclined quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it worked without any quote symbol.